# Failed to apply certificate pinning with Alamofire 5.0.2

Tags: ssl-certificate, alamofire, pinning

I am migrating my app to use Alamofire 5.0.2, in the past version it uses Alamofire 4.x and the certificate pinning is working fine.

Then I migrated Alamofire and its certificate pinning configuration with these changes:

```swift
//Usage example of the function `defaultSessionManager`
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let sessionManager = defaultSessionManager(defaultRequestInterceptor())
    //...
}

private func defaultSessionManager(_ requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor?) -> Alamofire.Session {

  let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "https://myapp.com": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: pinnedCertificates()),
  ]

  let configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10 // seconds

  return Alamofire.Session(
    configuration: configuration,
    interceptor: requestInterceptor,
    serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators))
}

func pinnedCertificates() -> [SecCertificate] {

  var certificates: [SecCertificate] = []
  let directoryContents: [URL] = //...

  let certificateName: String = "app.cer" // Replaced for the demo

  let pinnedCertificateURL: URL? = directoryContents.first { (url: URL) in url.lastPathComponent == certificateName }

  if let pinnedCertificateURL: URL = pinnedCertificateURL {
    do {
      let pinnedCertificateData: CFData = try Data(contentsOf: pinnedCertificateURL) as CFData
      if let pinnedCertificate: SecCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, pinnedCertificateData) {
        certificates.append(pinnedCertificate)
      }
    } catch {
        //...
    }
  }
  return certificates
}
```

With the solution above, I am getting the error:

```
MyApp[374:21470] Task <DDC8F9FD-81A3-EBA4-8AA2-D7C99DD3E63B>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

If I remove the line `serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators))`, Alamofire works but without certificate pinning.

Any idea how to solve this and what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` in your evaluator mapping should only be the host, not a full url:

```swift
let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "myapp.com": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: pinnedCertificates()),
  ]
```

Also, you need to make sure the host exactly matches the domains you're making requests against.

Additionally, Alamofire will automatically find certificates in your bundle so you may not need to find it yourself.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work. :(

Also we don't ship the certificate bundled.

Comment: here is the implementation using Alamofire 4.x: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/a62958a6ac2f9506c1becb5cf45ffa13

Comment: Jon, I find the new documentation for Alamofire 5.0 very confusing. I am unable to release a update of my app due this problem and I can't see any solution for this.

Comment: Your previous version doesn't use Alamofire's certificate pinning, it seems to be entirely custom. You define no actual policies and just check to see if the returned certificate is in your local certificates. Are you sure that even worked? If you want custom behavior, you can implement your own `ServerTrustEvaluating` type.

Comment: You could also subclass `SessionDelegate` to override the trust evaluation like you did before.

Comment: Well it passed in the pentest :) Strange situation.

Comment: It's working now. I will change it to the Alamofire's on solution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your previous usage also seemed to be using the public keys rather than the certificates, in which case you'd want to use `PublicKeysTrustEvaluator`.

Comment: Both solutions using `PublicKeysTrustEvaluator(keys: pinnedKeys())` and `PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: pinnedCertificates())` are working, which one you recommend? Probably the `pinnedCertificates` one?

Comment: Pinned keys are more flexible, as you can update certs with the same keys and not have to deploy a new app, but certificates have more checks. So really it comes down to your cert deployment strategy.

Comment: Could someone link me to a public key pinning implementation? I cannot find any reliable links and have no prior knowledge in this subject.